# Information included in same paths

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get some info under the `div class="row"` as in the figure. In particular I am interested in the col-md-7 values (I deleted fo privacy the information included there).
I've tried using `find_element_by_xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'col-md-7')]").get_attribute('textContent')
```

but it extracts only the first value, not the others.

[image]

For each element that I am interested in (for example, a `my_list =['url1','url2','url3']`), I'd like to have a pandas df as follows:

```
Url     Name   Org   Add  Country ...
url1
url2
url3
```

Does anyone know how to extract separately these fields to get a pandas df?

Comment: the website for reference is who.is (but I'd prefer to not include in both question and answer, whether possible)

Comment: 1.Does the Xpath you tried get the correct result/element?. 2.if you can edit your question with more of the HTML instead of a photo that would help. 3. If you will provide the URL you are likely to get a correct answer, so we can test it

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem? what tags _exactly_ are you trying to scrape? what si "Name" "org"...

Comment: I am tying to check if it works. I am trying to extract Name, Organization, Address, Country in Contact Information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a global dictionary and append all the elements to it. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver


links = ["https://who.is/whois/stackoverflow.com", "https://who.is/whois/python.org"]
data = {}
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    data.setdefault("url", []).append(link)

    for tag in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        # Selects the data under "Registrant Contact Information"
        ".rawWhois div:nth-of-type(1) .row"
    ):
        # Finds the first column
        data.setdefault(tag.find_element_by_tag_name("strong").text, []).append(
            # Finds the second column
            tag.find_element_by_class_name("col-md-7").text
        )


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index").transpose()
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
                              url                  Name                Organization                    Address                  City State / Province           Postal Code Country                 Phone Email                   Fax
0  https://who.is/whois/stackoverflow.com         Sysadmin Team        Stack Exchange, Inc.  110 William St , Floor 28              New York               NY                 10038      US       Non-Public Data        REDACTED FOR PRIVACY
1         https://who.is/whois/python.org  REDACTED FOR PRIVACY  Python Software Foundation       REDACTED FOR PRIVACY  REDACTED FOR PRIVACY           Oregon  REDACTED FOR PRIVACY      US  REDACTED FOR PRIVACY                        None
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `ValueError: arrays must all be same length` due to `---> 24 df = pd.DataFrame({"urls": urls, "name": name, "org": org})`. Is there anything that I need to replace in `get_attribute("...")`?

Comment: @LdM What was just an example. I'm not sure what you want to scrape, what is Name, Organization, Address, Country , can you share a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: There are multiple tables on the page, such as "Registrant Contact Information" and "Administrative Contact Information:" which ones do you want?